# как настроить mirror в unity под андроид

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity-mirror

создал простенькую игру в unity, сделал ее мультиплеерной через mirror, если на пк запустить несколько приложений и сконектить как двух игроков то все хорошо работает, но если сбилдить под телефоны то тут уже проблема, два телефона подключены к одной сети wifi, но они не могут соединиться друг с другом, пробовал запустить два эмулятора на одном пк и попробовать там, но тоже без успешно, в строке подключения к серверу писал localhost и пробовал через myip сайты узнать ip устройства хоста и подключиться через него, но тоже безуспешно, если есть знающие люди, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: У каждого устройства в сети есть уникальный IP адрес локальной сети. Его не узнать через сайты, а только в настройках Wi-fi подключения на самом телефоне можно посмотреть. У компьютера, где сервер тоже есть адрес, обычно начинается на 192.168.x.x., его и используйте для подключения. В Windows адрес можно посмотреть в cmd консоли командой ipconfig.

Comment: @aepot а как узнать ip телефона в сети?

Comment: В телефоне свойства подключения посмотрите, там есть.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите про Network Discovery. Есть и шаблон, как компонент и в документации об этом написано.

Если кратко, он делает всю работу за Вас, ища доступные сервера, это должно будет помочь подключится двум телефонам на одной wifi сети.